# First React Project, had error with module, now don't know what is error

Tags: reactjs, npm, module, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhLjx.png)
Firstly everything worked fine, then I got this error out of nowhere, tried searching online without success and on top of that now even can't start a project[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wegh.png)
Unbelievable, I don't know what to do now.

I searched stackoverflow and asked chatGPT but unsuccessful

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)